# Morris JS Chart Not Loading in Twitter Bootstrap Tab Pane

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Morris JS chart trying to load within a Twitter Bootstrap tab pane. The tabs work fine, but the chart will not load.

It looks like this article discusses the problem: http://www.doidea.se/blog/morris-js-charts-in-bootstrap-tabs

How would I translate their solution into my Rails code?

Here is my code:

**View:**

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
    <%= content_tag :div, "", id: "info_chart", data: { info: @chart_data } %>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

**Application.JS**

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

**ControllerName.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
  # only use morris if the post chart element is on the page.
  if $('#info_chart').length > 0
    Morris.Bar
      element: 'info_chart'
      data: $('#info_chart').data('info')
      xkey: 'x'
      ykeys: ['y']
      labels: ['label']
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?  Do you see the chart svg tags in the page source?

Answer (score 12):

Found a solution to my situation for a single chart on tabs that wasn't display properly:

Save your graph as a variable:

```
var usage_graph = Morris.Line({
  // config
});
```

Then listen for changes on the tabs, and redraw the graph:

```
$('ul.nav a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    usage_graph.redraw();
});
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I'm having what I believe is the same issue with my Morris charts in Slick carousel. Pretty sure your fix translates somehow. Here, what is 'shown.bs.tab'? Isn't that a selector? @DevatoTech

Comment: These are bootstrap js events. From the docs: "This event fires on tab show after a tab has been shown"- http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: You could create your chart in event handler instead of redrawing it (no need to creating if not going to be shown). Also you could use jQuery's `one` instead of `on` so chart is drawn only once and it will work on next tab switch

Comment: While this works to some degree, it still cuts off half the chart from page!

Comment: This actually only partially worked for me, I had to also add svg{
  width: 100% !important;
} to the CSS

Answer (score 2):

The top answer is partially correct. The problem, however, is the svg is not resized. In order to make sure the svg is resized, you can modify it by css:

```
    if ($('#morris-stacked-bar-graph').length > 0) {
        var morris_bar = Morris.Bar({
            element: 'morris-stacked-bar-graph',
            data: [
                {x: '2011 Q1', y: 3, z: 2, a: 3},
                {x: '2011 Q2', y: 2, z: null, a: 1},
                {x: '2011 Q3', y: 0, z: 2, a: 4},
                {x: '2011 Q4', y: 2, z: 4, a: 3}
            ],
            xkey: 'x',
            ykeys: ['y', 'z', 'a'],
            labels: ['Y', 'Z', 'A'],
            stacked: true,
            barColors: $('#morris-stacked-bar-graph').data('colors').split(',')
        });
        $('ul.nav a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            morris_bar.redraw();
            $('svg').css({ width: '100%' });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to check that you are using the correct version of morris.js, the current master branch on github has the redraw() function.

Second: Make sure that you are able to print a graph in the dom on say, you first active tab.

Third: Add another graph element in a tab that is not active, add data-identifiers for each tab to be able to redraw multiple graphs using:

```
$('ul.nav a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    var types = $(this).attr("data-identifier");
    var typesArray = types.split(",");
    $.each(typesArray, function (key, value) {
        eval(value + ".redraw()");
    })
});
```

This js will determine which data-identifiers are concerned whenever a tab is 'shown', you can have multiple graph elements separated by commas for instance. 
It will then take the value/values of the identifier, which obviously would be the same as your graph elements and call the redraw() function on them.

I see no need to make it more railsy than that for this, you could always convert to coffeescript ofcourse, but this should work.

Comment: I changed the "gem 'morrisjs-rails'" line in my gemfile to "gem 'morrisjs-rails', git: 'https://github.com/beanieboi/morrisjs-rails'" and your code. One chart is working in the first tab as it was before, but no charts show in the other tabs.

Comment: The gem uses the production instance of morris, 0.4.3 the same that you'll find on the developers site, you need to download the master-version from github: https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/ which is currently 0.5.0.

Comment: How are things going?

Comment: If I download it, where do I put it in my Rails app?

Comment: You would out it in your assets/js folder, and in your application.js file you would simply reference your file: //= require morris

Comment: Add the morris.js in 'vendor/assets/javascript' and morris.css in 'vendor/assets/stylesheets'. include "require morris" in your application.js and and application.css

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me, try it if you have multiple Chart on one tab:

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
$.each(yourarray, function (index, value) {
                value.redraw();
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem, but in my case none of the above solutions worked.

What worked for me was to use the **jquery ui tabs**  instead ([link](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/)). These worked like a charm.

Your code would only need slight re-writing. Instead of

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
    <%= content_tag :div, "", id: "info_chart", data: { info: @chart_data } %>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

write:

```
    <!-- Nav tabs and Panes-->
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
      <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>


      <div  id="home">...</div>
      <div  id="profile">
        <%= content_tag :div, "", id: "info_chart", data: { info: @chart_data } %>
      </div>
      <div id="messages">...</div>
      <div  id="settings">...</div>
 </div>
```

And then you just add this script:

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
```

I hope this helps.

BTW all the fiddles I've found that try to catch event `'shown.bs.tab'` don't work anymore for some reason.